# Make webpart available in gallery for sub-site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I am currently making some updates to an existing SharePoint 2010 site used by my company as the Intranet.

The site structure is as follows:

- Parent Site

  - Subsite A

    - Subsite B

Currently, when I edit a page on Subsite A, I can see a particular custom Web part listed in the Web part Gallery but when I go to edit a page on Subsite B, I do not see that Web part in the Web part gallery.

My question is: how do I make a Web part available in the Subsite A gallery also available in Subsite B gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the site features page of your subsite B contains the web part feature and activate it if it is not activated.
The url is `subsiteB/_layouts/ManageFeatures.aspx`. The link for the page is located in `Site settings -> Site Actions -> Manage site features`

You can read more about feature scopes [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-2010-feature-scopes-activation/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - I will check this tomorrow when I get into work!